# Should I use POST or PUT for API call that can create or update

Tags: rest, laravel, restful-url

I wonder if I should use POST or PUT for my API call.

The backend will either create or update an existing row in my DB. I know that I use POST for creating and PUT for updating, but what should I use when I dont know which one will get toggeled create/update ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that the create/update distinction is the best way to decide between PUT and POST. This is backed up by the [rest cook book](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/):

> The HTTP methods POST and PUT aren't the HTTP equivalent of the CRUD's create and update.

I recommend that you read that article, but as some of the comments there have said they don't get it, I will try to explain in another way.

1. Ask yourself what happens if you make a GET request to the same URL directly after the PUT or POST request. If you get back the same data that you just PUT or POSTed, then it should probably be a PUT request. If you have to go to a different URL to see the data, then it should probably be a POST (and you can use the Location header in the response to tell the client where the POSTed data can be viewed with a GET request).
2. **Idempotency** is much more important than create/update or indeed whether I can make a GET request to the same URL. PUT requests are idempotent (repeating the same request multiple times has the same effect as making it once) whereas POST requests are not (making the same request multiple times is not the same as making it once). If your request has additional side effects each time it is made, then you MUST use POST.

It sounds like your request is idempotent, and that you know the exact URL the resource will live at up front, so I think you should probably use PUT.

As expressed in the Rest cook book article, it is completely fine to use PUT for both resource creation and updating.

If you can use PUT then you should because it gives clients more information about the service. For example, fault tolerance, resiliency and distribution is much easier with PUT requests because you don't care if the same request happens multiple times. Building fault tolerant applications that make POST requests can be a little trickier because you have to ensure that the request only happens once. Implementing re-try logic is also easier the PUT because you don't care where the request failed, you can just re-try because of idempotency.

Implementing a retry for POST is a little harder because the client is not really sure if the request succeeded or not, and it has to assume that making multiple POST requests could be damaging.

Answer (score 0):

Use **PUT** api call.
**POST** is mostly used when data is created.

Comment: But the data can also be created, or is it "ok" to use PUT for both create and update?

Comment: If that is the case then you can use POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea what to use, use POST. If you aren't too sure, consult this: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/